# single button can have multiple methods?

Tags: c#

I have these 4 buttons.

`truncateEmp` `truncateStocks` `truncateLogs` `truncateExpenses`

If I press one of these, a new form will open, and will ask the user for the password from the database. If the password is correct, it will truncate the table.

The new form has two buttons, `proceed` and `cancel`. Of course, `cancel`, closes the form and `proceed` will check the user's pass if its correct, then do it's job.

Is it possible if `proceed` can truncate other tables? I can only truncate `Employees` table because `proceed_Click` has only one method.

```
private void proceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //proceed
    {

        string pass = passField.Text;
        if (pass == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Did you input something? I doubt it.");
            return;
        }

        bool r = validate_login(pass);
        if (r)
        {
            db_connection();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE Employees";
            cmd.Connection = connect;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Success!", "TRUNCATE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            emp.ShowDataToGrid();
            logs.Log_TruncateEmp();
            this.Close();
            passField.Clear();

            connect.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password!", "TRUNCATE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            passField.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //cancel
    {
        this.Close();
    }   
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just do: `proceed.Click += MyMethod;` where `MyMethod` is a function with an `object` and an `EventArgs` parameter.

Comment: @Ian will definitely try. Thank you!

Comment: Easiest way is to extend the command text to truncate other tables. The elegant way could be using a delegate or a generic method. Its up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button.Click` is an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/), and yes, multiple methods may be attached to such events.

The way methods work is basically that multiple actions may be executed if an event triggers. So if you have 3 methods assigned to your `proceed.Click` event, then all 3 will execute.

Here is an example, showing how 2 click events can be attached to a single button:

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    proceed.Click += MyClickEvent1;
    proceed.Click += MyClickEvent2;
}

public void MyClickEvent1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do Stuff ...
}
public void MyClickEvent2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do More Stuff ...
}
```